# android UNSUPPORTED The return value to indicate that the device does not support the statistic

Tags: android

here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html it says

```
int UNSUPPORTED The return value to indicate that the device does not support the statistic.
```

It doesn't say what method this returns. Is that something common every developer (apart from myself...) knows?

thanks, A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods (apart from `public static long getUidRxBytes (int uid)`) in `TrafficStats` seems to return `UNSUPPORTED`. It is a constant value that is used to indicate that the requested statistic is unavailable for this device.

Quick code sample:

```
final long bytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
if (bytes != TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
   // Supported on this device
} else {
   // Not supported on this device
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that usage requires at least [Android API Level 8](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level8).